# Passing a value as an integer but it represents to be a String

Tags: python-3.x

> When an integer value is inserted dynamically in below program those
>   dynamica values are turned to be a string. Kindly help me to get popup
>   message like "Integers don't have length." when I pass int value.

```
def cond_act(a):
        if type(a) == int:
            return "Integers don't have length."
        else:
            return len(a)

a=input("Enter a Value: ")
print(cond_act(a))


Output:

Enter a Value: 10
2
```

Comment: Think you are looking for `int(input())`

Comment: I can use int(input()) as well, but here in my code I want to find length of the string. So If the pass integer value it has to throw an error like "Int values don't have length"

Comment: Even with your edit it is still not clear to me exactly what you are after, but guessing that you might need to use  [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit), [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal), or [`str.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) to check the string in your function (in place of where you are currently using `type()`).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply (try to) convert the input to an int with a call to int(a).

Answer (score 0):

```
def cond_act(a):
    try:
        b=int(a)
        if b == int(a):
            if type(b) == int:
                return "Sorry, integers don't have length."
        else:
            return
    except ValueError:
        return len(a)

#print(cond_act("hi"))
a=input("Enter String value in-order to find length: ")
print(cond_act(a))
```